# Better database structure

Tags: sql, windows-phone-8

I'm developing app for WP8 that can store documents of dozen predefined types (e.g. passport, insurance...).
So, I have table with columns like this: `int id, string name, int order`

The problem is that other fields are not same for different document types.

For passport it will be: `number int, photo Bitmap`

For insurance: `number int, holder string`

First way to resolve that problem: store all that data in XML column.
Second: store each type in dedicated table (I'm afraid that Linq query will be really huge and slow to get data from 10 different tables).
Third: store all meta in another tables (e.g. table `field_types`, `field_to_docs`, `field_values`).

I think fastest way will be, of course, XML. What do you think about it?
How about storing Bitmaps in XML, or I'll need to create another table specially for storing Bitmaps and than sync them will references from XML?

Comment: *I think fastest way will be, of course, XML.* Nope.

Comment: I mean fastest to implement

Answer (score 0):

I'd model a main table Document, and then a small table for each document type with its peculiarities.

In DOCUMENT you'd have all the common fields plus the type of document
In the small tables an ID to the main table and the fields unique to this type of document.

When retrieving documents, you'd have to do a JOIN on the foreign key but should be fast and simple.

Other option I'd consider is only one table with plenty of null-able fields and depending on the document type reconstructing one or other and leaving the other document-specific fields at null. If you are using a Object-oriented language then go for the first one. It's easier.